# How do I position div 4 to the right inside div 1

Tags: html, css

This is the code I have tried to use to make the `.div4` position to the right inside div 1

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: #A6C3EE;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 30px;
  height: 550px;
  width: 1200px;
  color: white;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: #BDE2FE;
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px;
  height: 450px;
  width: 300px;
}

.div3 {
  background-color: #BDE2FE;
  position: absolute;
  width: 450px;
  height: 150px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 15%;
  left: 45%;
  margin: 30px;
  margin-left: -150px;
}

.div4 {
  background-color: #BDE2FE;
  width: 100px;
  height: 450px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:#4C5979">
  <div class="div1">
    <h1>Website</h1>

    <div class="div2">
      <p>info about website </p>
      <img src="prototype3.png">

    </div>
    <!--div2-->
    <div class="div3">
      <p></p>

    </div>
    <!-- div3 -->
    <div class="div4">

      <div>hellow world</div>

    </div>
    <!-- div4-->
  </div>
  <!-- div1 -->
</body>
```

I've tried `position:fixed` and `position:relative` properties but they both give the same unwanted outcome, and I've also tired float property but that hasn't worked either

Comment: There are typos in your HTML: `<div class "div3">`, there should be an `=` character between the `class` attribute and its value, and there's also a stray `<p>` just inside that element. Can you possibly add a picture to your question to show the layout you're hoping to create?

Answer (score 2):

Add `position: absolute;` to `.div4`, then you can put div4 wherever you want by direction properties (top, right, left, bottom). in case that you want to position div4 to the right inside div1 you can use the following:

```
.div4 {
  background-color: #BDE2FE;
  width: 100px;
  height: 450px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
  /****************/
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0
  /****************/
}
```

Comment: ```top: 0``` is not necessary, Correct Answer

Comment: @MahdiarMransouri If you found the answer to be correct, then consider upvoting the answer too.

Comment: you're right, answer upvoted, good luck